# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Unable to upload to play Store

Tags: android, flutter, code-signing

I recently switched my app to flutter which was previously pure java based and the app had previous presence in play store where Google was managing it's app signing key.

Now when I tried to generate bundle using same old .jks key through flutter and tried to upload to play store, I get following error:

> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
> SHA1: 98:42:A0:2B:8F:A7:1A:42:A1:5D:E3:8D:45:92:3D:E7:9A:D1:84:8A
> but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:
> SHA1: 16:73:6C:3D:DC:89:BB:7B:1C:E7:17:DA:0C:7C:9F:B0:2F:76:F8:89

local.properties:

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\decen\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
ndk.dir=C:\\Users\\decen\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\24.0.7956693
flutter.sdk=C:\\src\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=7.4.5
flutter.versionCode=145
```

key.properties

```
storePassword=Password
keyPassword=Password
keyAlias=key
storeFile=D:\\AndroidStudioKeys\\appName\\key.jks
```

app/build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        //signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Now, I can't manage to delete my existing project from Play store and start from scratch. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try contacting to the playstore support email and explain the issue, they might help you with that.

Comment: Off top - please don't share your passwords on the internet

Comment: What command have you used to build the bundle?

Comment: @EugenMartynov, command I used was `flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/appName/build/app/outputs/bundle/release`

Comment: Not an expert in the flutter - however, shouldn't you use `--release` flag?